# Objcopy, how it makes binary output?

Tags: compilation, binaryfiles, binutils, objcopy

As I'm new to binutils, gcc ant others, I have some general questions, anwsers on which I havn't found in manuals.

I'm using C and assembly(nasm syntax) and I need raw binary files on output. First of all, I compile my code to objec file with parameters:

```
cc -nostartfiles -nostdlib -c -ffreestanding <input file(s)> ;cc or gcc no matter
```

Then I link all the files using simple script which only puts segments in needed order.

```
ld -T <script> -o <o.file> <in.file(s)>  ;nothing special here
```

And to get raw binary I use objcopy

```
objcopy -O binary <o.file> <in.file> ;can't be simplier
```

All in all, I need binary file **only** with .text and .data segments in it and 32-bit code.

*1.Can i get this way what I want?*

*2.Are there other ways to do that? (no matter easier or more complicated)*

---

Thank you for help.

---

I haven't problems compiling Asm code, almost all problems with C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I came across a `ld` manual page and `/DISCARD/` block was said to exclude everything listed in it from final output.

So I've inserted this block after the `.text`, `.data` and `.bss` blocks

```
/DISCARD/ : 
{
    *(.comment)
    *(.eh_frame)
    *(.note.GNU-stack)
}
```

As well as this line in the very beginning of my linker script.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
```

Therefore, I do not need to use `objcopy` anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You need to compile the source files using this command

```
nasm -o bin <SOURCE FILES>
```

This will produce pure binary output.

Comment: nasm is a mere assembler, which can do nothing with the C source files in the project...